# Create a customizable list of book nodes

Tags: php, drupal, module

I'm working with Drupal and the book module right now, and it works perfectly for what I need.

The thing is, I need a way to print out a navigation similar to the one generated by the book block, but so that I can change what it outputs.

How do I print out a custom version of what the book block/book navigation prints out?  For example, so that I can change the HTML output.

I hope this is clear enough, and please let me know if I need to add anything to make the question more clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how you want to modify that block, but you have several options.

- If you don't need too big changes, probably it can be done with some CSS hacking
- There are a few modules that do similar things, for instance [Book Block](http://drupal.org/project/bookblock) or [Advanced Book Block](http://drupal.org/project/advancedbookblocks)
- Finally, you can always check out the book_block function, which prints the block and create a custom block with the necessary modifications